# Collision Detection in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

For a 3D Game using OpenGL i have to implement a simple collision detection. After thinking about that, i have had the idea to read out the `glm::mat4 MVP` values and compare them to each other. Is that a practicable approach? As a first step, i output each MVP Matrix with `glm::to_string(MVP)` but to my surprise, that causes a big loss of performance (frame rate is decreased factor 5). So is that a bad idea to fulfill my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to convert the MVP matrix to a string? You could use the raw values even faster than you could parse a string.

Furthermore, That doesn't supply you with enough information. That could tell you where the object is, how it's rotated, and how RELATIVELY large it is, it couldn't tell you how large it ACTUALLY is or where it could collide relative to that. eg. you could render a dragon and the player with the exact same MVP matrix and see that their collisions are going to be completely different.

I would first start with an AABB around each object. Basically, you go through each point of each mesh, find the maximum (x, y, z) of each vertex on the mesh, minimal vector (x, y, z) on each mesh. Multiply each of those points by the MVP and you have a cube that every point of the object is in (A bounding volume.) to test if anything is within that, you see if it's between the min and max points of the bounding volume. That is the basics of collision detection.

This concept has many other forms, OBB (Oriented Bounding Box), Bounding Sphere, Bounding Capsule, etc.

Pseudo Code:

```
struct
{
    float x, y, z;
} Vec; // use the GLM alternative

struct
{
    Vec min; // no particular order, as long as they are ordered.
    Vec max;
} AABB;

AABB GetAABB(const Mesh& mesh)
{
    Vec min, max;
    foreach position in mesh.vertices
    {
        if (p.x < min.x) min.x = p.x;
        if (p.y < min.y) min.y = p.y;
        if (p.z < min.z) min.z = p.z;

        if (p.x > max.x) max.x = p.x;
        if (p.y > max.y) max.y = p.y;
        if (p.z > max.z) max.z = p.z;
    }

    AABB box;
    box.min = min;
    box.max = max;

    return box;
}

bool Collides(AABB a, AABB b)
{
    int meetingAxies = 0; // how many axies are colliding between the AABBs (must be at least 3 to be true)

    if ( (b.min.x > a.min.x) && (b.min.x < a.max.x) ) meetingAxies++;
    if ( (b.min.y > a.min.y) && (b.min.y < a.max.y) ) meetingAxies++;
    if ( (b.min.z > a.min.z) && (b.min.z < a.max.z) ) meetingAxies++;

    return meetingAxies == 3;
}
```